# Not Passing my edit text value in android to PHP variable

Tags: php, android

I'm able to connect into my MySQL database but the problem is. My android does not passing the edit text value to PHP with this codes.

```
public class MySQL extends Activity {

    EditText inputName;
     private static String  url_create_product = "http://atlantis-us.com/phpFile.php?";

     JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_sql);
        inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt1);

       ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsend)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new CreateNewProduct().execute();
        }
    });

    }

    class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String name = inputName.getText().toString();
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);

            return null;
        }

    }

}



this is my PHP codes

<?php

    $DB_HostName = "localhost";
    $DB_Name = "_atlantisdb";
    $DB_User = "atlantis_frux";
    $DB_Pass = "frux2012";
    $DB_Table = "testDB";

    if (isset ($_GET["name"]))
        $name = $_GET["name"];
    else
        $name = "Ghalia";

    $con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$con) or die(mysql_error()); 

    $sql = "insert into $DB_Table (name) values('$name');";
    $res = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_close($con);
    if ($res) {
        echo "success";
    }else{
        echo "faild";
    }// end else

?>
```

can anyone trace what's worng with my codes?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the edit text value using `POST` method in your android code and getting the value using method `GET` in your php code.

```
chage $_GET["name"] to $_POST["name"] or $_REQUEST['name']
```

Comment: what if I change this JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "GET", params);

Comment: yes you have to use same methods on both server and client side

Comment: I already use this  JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "GET", params); but still not working

Comment: can u post makeHttpRequest() method